# How do I refer to a specific variable list item in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, list

My code grabs information and stores it in a list. The sorted list is:

```
example/
example/text1.txt
example/text2.txt
example/text3.txt
```

I would like to refer to text1.txt and perform a function to it, then move on to the next entry in the list (in this case, text2.txt).

I was able to see a bit of what I can do with regex, but it outputs nothing.
Here's a portion of my code so far:

```
FileNames = name in sorted(zip_file.namelist())
regex = r"[1-9]+ \d"
matches = re.findall(regex, str(FileNames))

for match in matches:
    print("%s" % (match))
```

EDIT:
utilizing a different technique, here's what I got so far:

```
import zipfile
import re
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('/example.zip','r')
#zip_file = zipfile.ZipFIle(input("What's the filepath?: "))
for name in sorted(zip_file.namelist()):
#print(name) 
for file_path in name:
    file_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]
    if "1" in file_name:
        print(file_name)
    else:
        print("This line does not contain a valid path to a text file.")
zip_file.close()
```

It gives me a really gross output, something along the lines of

```
example/text1.txt
The Line does not contain a valid path to a text file.
```

^repeated a ton of times

Comment: what type of functions do you want to perform on `text1.txt` and other `.txt` files? do you want to handle it as a file and possibly read & write to `text1.txt` and need a way to assign a file handle to it?

Comment: @davedwards e x a c t l y. You nailed it

Comment: if `regex` is not required consider removing that tag

Comment: the output repeats "a ton of times" because the nested `for`-loops is iterating over `filepath` as strings, each repeat for a character in the filename, not actually *reading* the file contents, as you may have expected. Instead, remove the second `for`-loop. Altogether try this: `for file_name in sorted(zip_file.namelist()):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read().strip())` will, for example, `print` the contents of each `.txt` file in `example.zip`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex but just a simple `split` since you are dealing with paths. For each line, you can take the rightmost string of the list after `"/"` if it exists. If it contains `".txt"`it's your file name, otherwise ignore that line.

```
files_paths = ["example/",
               "example/text1.txt",
               "example/text2.txt",
               "example/text3.txt"]

for file_path in files_paths :
    file_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]
    if ".txt" in file_name:
        ... # call a function with file_name as an argument.
    else:
        print("This line does not contain a valid path to a text file.")
```

The `print` is just there for testing of course, feel free to delete the `else` clause if you want your script to stay silent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every entry in the list is a path to a file with which you want to perform some work on, you can use the os.path library to get the basename of the file path.

```
import os
path_str = "example/text1.txt"
file_name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path_str))
```